# ROS Answers SE migration: ros2 ubuntu 23

Tags: ros2, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, will ros2 be available soon on ubuntu 23 or is it worth to install still 22?

I am currently trying with ubuntu 23 and ros2 rolling, but get issues with

command:

```
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -y --skip-keys "fastcdr rti-connext-dds-6.0.1 urdfdom_headers" --os=ubuntu:jammy
```

->

```
ERROR: the following rosdeps failed to install
  apt: command [sudo -H apt-get install -y python3-catkin-pkg-modules] failed
```

Thank you
D

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/415326/ros2-ubuntu-23/) by [DrunkenRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/148730/drunkenrobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2023-05-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> will ros2 be available soon on ubuntu 23

Both Rolling and Iron Irwini [only support Ubuntu Jammy](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html#iron-irwini-may-2023-november-2024).

I'm not aware of any ROS 2 release which has plans to support Ubuntu `23.x`.

> is it worth to install still 22?

Ubuntu Jammy is an LTS release. According to [The Ubuntu lifecycle and release cadence](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle), it will be supported until (at least) 2032. That's about 9 years from now.

We can't know your requirements, but at least from the perspective of "would Ubuntu 22 be supported long enough?", I'd say, *yes*.

ROS 2 Humble (first ROS 2 release to support Jammy) is also LTS, and [will be supported until 2027](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-2000.html#humble-hawksbill-may-2022-may-2027).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2023-05-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DrunkenRobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/148730/drunkenrobot/) on 2023-05-13**:
Thank you for the feedback. I have no special reason, i just did a new setup for a ros development machine and picked the latest version ... not realizing that ros is bound to a distro (more or less)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2023-05-13**:\

> not realizing that ros is bound to a distro (more or less)

well .. in general that's only really true if you want to be able to install binary packages.

YMMV, but I've had good success building ROS on all sorts of Linux distributions -- provided the base dependencies are available.